# What are the Seven Kingdoms in Aquaman?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, aquaman-2018

What are the Seven Kingdoms in the *Aquaman* film? These are the ones I caught in the film, but I think I missed the others.

1. Atlantis: ruled by Orm (at beginning of the film)
2. Xebel: ruled by King Nereus
3. Trench

Comment: https://www.cbr.com/aquaman-seven-kingdom-atlantis-explained/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Atlantis. No need to explain that one, I think.
2. Xebel, which as you said is ruled by King Nereus. IIRC Xebel isn't shown in the movie.
3. The Trench, inhabited by monsters.
4. The Fishermen Kingdom, <s>land</s> waters of the mermaid-looking people.
5. The Brine, with its crab-like people, and where the final battle begins.
6. The Deserters Kingdom, now buried in the Sahara after it was draught.
7. > The Hidden Sea (in Earth's Core, no less), where Atlan's trident was hidden, and which can be accessed from the portal thingy beyond the Trench.

Comment: Just as a confirmation the seven kingdoms are all addressed in the film during the meeting of Atlantis and Xebel, just before the submarine attack. Though technically they address the 7th kingdom by the name mentioned in the link above by @Valorum.